# MySQL show used index in query

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, query-optimization, explain

For example I have created 3 index:

- `click_date` - `transaction` table, `daily_metric` table
- `order_date` - `transaction` table

I want to check does  my query use index, I use EXPLAIN function and get this result:

```
+----+--------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table        | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <derived2>   | ALL   | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL |    668 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
|  2 | DERIVED      | <derived3>   | ALL   | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL |    645 |                                              |
|  2 | DERIVED      | <derived4>   | ALL   | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL |    495 |                                              |
|  4 | DERIVED      | transaction  | ALL   | order_date    | NULL       | NULL    | NULL | 291257 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  3 | DERIVED      | daily_metric | range | click_date    | click_date | 3       | NULL | 812188 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  5 | UNION        | <derived7>   | ALL   | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL |    495 |                                              |
|  5 | UNION        | <derived6>   | ALL   | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL |    645 | Using where; Not exists                      |
|  7 | DERIVED      | transaction  | ALL   | order_date    | NULL       | NULL    | NULL | 291257 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  6 | DERIVED      | daily_metric | range | click_date    | click_date | 3       | NULL | 812188 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union2,5>   | ALL   | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL |   NULL |                                              |
+----+--------------+--------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

In `EXPLAIN` results I see, that index `order_date` of transaction table is not used, do I correct understand ?
Index click_date of `daily_metric` table was used correct ?

Please tell my how to understand from `EXPLAIN` result does my created index is used in query properly ?

My query:

```
SELECT
    partner_id,
    the_date,
    SUM(clicks) as clicks,
    SUM(total_count) as total_count,
    SUM(count) as count,
    SUM(total_sum) as total_sum,
    SUM(received_sum) as received_sum,
    SUM(partner_fee) as partner_fee
    FROM (
        SELECT
            clicks.partner_id,
            clicks.click_date as the_date,
            clicks,
            orders.total_count,
            orders.count,
            orders.total_sum,
            orders.received_sum,
            orders.partner_fee
        FROM
            (SELECT
                partner_id, click_date, sum(clicks) as clicks
            FROM
                daily_metric WHERE DATE(click_date) BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-30'
            GROUP BY partner_id , click_date) as clicks
            LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT
                partner_id,
                    DATE(order_date) as order_dates,
                    SUM(order_sum) as total_sum,
                    SUM(customer_paid_sum) as received_sum,
                    SUM(partner_fee) as partner_fee,
                    count(*) as total_count,
                    count(CASE
                        WHEN status = 1 THEN 1
                        ELSE NULL
                    END) as count
            FROM
                transaction WHERE DATE(order_date) BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-30'
            GROUP BY DATE(order_date) , partner_id) as orders ON orders.partner_id = clicks.partner_id AND clicks.click_date = orders.order_dates
        UNION ALL SELECT
            orders.partner_id,
            orders.order_dates as the_date,
            clicks,
            orders.total_count,
            orders.count,
            orders.total_sum,
            orders.received_sum,
            orders.partner_fee
        FROM
            (SELECT
                partner_id, click_date, sum(clicks) as clicks
            FROM
                daily_metric  WHERE DATE(click_date) BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-30'
            GROUP BY partner_id , click_date) as clicks
                RIGHT JOIN
            (SELECT
                partner_id,
                    DATE(order_date) as order_dates,
                    SUM(order_sum) as total_sum,
                    SUM(customer_paid_sum) as received_sum,
                    SUM(partner_fee) as partner_fee,
                    count(*) as total_count,
                    count(CASE
                        WHEN status = 1 THEN 1
                        ELSE NULL
                    END) as count
            FROM
                transaction  WHERE DATE(order_date) BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2013-04-30'
            GROUP BY DATE(order_date) , partner_id) as orders ON orders.partner_id = clicks.partner_id AND clicks.click_date = orders.order_dates
        WHERE
            clicks.partner_id is NULL
        ORDER BY the_date DESC
        ) as t
        GROUP BY the_date ORDER BY the_date DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Can you actually show the query you are trying to run?  We really need to see both parts to better assess an option for you.

Comment: @DRapp I'm updated post.

Comment: @Strawberry what missing ?

Comment: Either way, rather than try to clean this up, I'd be sorely tempted to start over, but for that we'd need proper DDLs and a desired result set.

Comment: I'm update post, now is full query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can't explain what the EXPLAIN has dumped, I thought there must be an easier solution to what you have and came up with the following.  I would suggest the following indexes to optimize your existing query for the WHERE date range and grouping by partner.

Additionally, when you have a query that uses a FUNCTION on a field, it doesn't take advantage of the index.  Such as your DATE(order_date) and DATE(click_date).  To allow the index to better be used, qualify the full date/time such as 12:00am (morning) up to 11:59pm.  I would typically to this via

```
x >= someDate @12:00 and x < firstDayAfterRange.
```

in your example would be (notice less than May 1st which gets up to April 30th at 11:59:59pm)

```
click_date >= '2013-04-01' AND click_date < '2013-05-01'

Table         Index
transaction   (order_date, partner_id)
daily_metric  (click_date, partner_id)
```

Now, an adjustment.  Since your clicks table may have entries the transactions dont, and vice-versa, I would adjust this query to do a pre-query of all possible date/partners, then left-join to respective aggregate queries such as:

```
SELECT
      AllParnters.Partner_ID,
      AllParnters.the_Date,
      coalesce( clicks.clicks, 0 ) Clicks,
      coalesce( orders.total_count, 0 ) TotalCount,
      coalesce( orders.count, 0 ) OrderCount,
      coalesce( orders.total_sum, 0 ) OrderSum,
      coalesce( orders.received_sum, 0 ) ReceivedSum,
      coalesce( orders.partner_fee 0 ) PartnerFee
   from 
      ( select distinct
              dm.partner_id, 
              DATE( dm.click_date ) as the_Date
           FROM
              daily_metric dm
           WHERE 
              dm.click_date >= '2013-04-01' AND dm.click_date < '2013-05-01'
        UNION
        select
              t.partner_id,
              DATE(t.order_date) as the_Date
           FROM
              transaction t
           WHERE 
              t.order_date >= '2013-04-01' AND t.order_date < '2013-05-01' ) AllParnters

      LEFT JOIN
         ( SELECT
                 dm.partner_id, 
                 DATE( dm.click_date ) sumDate, 
                 sum( dm.clicks) as clicks
              FROM
                 daily_metric dm
              WHERE 
                 dm.click_date >= '2013-04-01' AND dm.click_date < '2013-05-01'
             GROUP BY 
                dm.partner_id, 
                DATE( dm.click_date )  ) as clicks
         ON AllPartners.partner_id = clicks.partner_id
         AND AllPartners.the_date = clicks.sumDate

      LEFT JOIN
      ( SELECT 
              t.partner_id,
              DATE(t.order_date) as sumDate,
              SUM(t.order_sum) as total_sum,
              SUM(t.customer_paid_sum) as received_sum,
              SUM(t.partner_fee) as partner_fee,
              count(*) as total_count,
              count(CASE WHEN t.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as COUNT
           FROM
              transaction t
           WHERE 
              t.order_date >= '2013-04-01' AND t.order_date < '2013-05-01'
           GROUP BY 
              t.partner_id,
              DATE(t.order_date) ) as orders 
         ON AllPartners.partner_id = orders.partner_id
         AND AllPartners.the_date = orders.sumDate
   order by
      AllPartners.the_date DESC
   limit 50 offset 0
```

This way, the first query will be quick on the index to get all possible combinations from EITHER table.  Then the left-join will AT MOST join to one row per set.  If found, get the number, if not, I am applying COALESCE() so if null, defaults to zero.

CLARIFICATION.

Like you when building your pre-aggregate queries of "clicks" and "orders", the "AllPartners" is the ALIAS result of the select distinct of partners and dates within the date range you were interested in.  The resulting columns of that where were "partner_id" and "the_date" respective to your next queries.  So this is the basis of joining to the aggregates of "clicks" and "orders".  So, since I have these two columns in the alias "AllParnters", I just grabbed those for the field list since they are LEFT-JOINed to the other aliases and may not exist in either/or the respective others.

Comment: I not understand what is `AllParnters.Partner_ID,
      AllParnters.the_Date,`

Comment: @TomasLiachovskis, revised answer for clarification